# ILRepack exe doesn't locate xaml file

Tags: wpf, ilmerge

I have a WPF exe I want to merge with its referenced libraries, so I tried ILRepack. The merging is done fine and the final executable is pretty fat.

But when I try to launch it, it stop to work, and when I debug in Visual Studio I get an "IOException - Cannot locate resource 'mainwinwows.xaml'" (the original message is in french, the translation might be not very accurate). The StartupUri is correct.

Here is my command line:

```
ILRepack.exe "C:\<Some path>\originalExe.exe" /lib:"C:\<Some path>\libsToInclude" /out:"C:\<Some path>\finalExe.exe" /log:"C:\<Some path>\logBuild.log" /target:winexe
```

Should I merge the xaml file with the other libraries ?

Comment: Note that you need to provide all libraries you want to merge on the command line, /lib is just for reference lookup folders.
Can you provide a reproduction project (or the exe/dll you're merging) ?
The exception stack trace may help as well.

Comment: Another question: Is the `mainwindovs.xaml` part of the main .exe or it's in the libraries?

Comment: @Timotei the .xaml is part of the exe.